# Убрать отображение 403 ошибки из консоли

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть ajax запрос, который подгружает нужную информацию. На серверной стороне различным группам пользователей некоторые страницы могут быть запрещены (сервер возвращает 403 статус). Если вернулся 403 ответ, то аяксом подгружается соответствующий контент ошибки. Все работает, но в консоли все еще отображается ошибка 403, которую я хотел бы убрать, каким образом это можно сделать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код JS

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '/lk/' + link,
            cache: false,
            success: function success(html) {
                $("#content").html(html);
                $(window).trigger('ajax');
            },
            statusCode: {
                403: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/lk/forbidden',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function success(html) {
                            $("#content").html(html);
                            $(window).trigger('ajax');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант просто подчистить консоль в success:

```
success: function success(html) {
    $("#content").html(html);
    $(window).trigger('ajax');
    console.clear();
}
```

Comment: А он всю консоль почистит?

Comment: Начисто. Всё что до.

Comment: тогда не очень хорошее решение, полезную информацию тоже сотрёт

Comment: На крайний случай сойдет, но мало ли тут можно перехватить ошибку и не выводить ее, типа try {} catch ($ex) {return false;} Но я не очень понимаю как это реализовать на js